# Colors for table header border not changing

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the header of my table a different color, but the borders are staying the original color.
[image]

This is my CSS

```
 .dashboard th {
        background-color: green;
        border: 0px solid green;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Why are the borders not changing color?

Comment: It might cause css priority, cache, etc. Anyways, may we see your html as well?

Comment: Can you add a class to the rows you want to change to green and adjust the color of the entire row? You could also add `border-spacing:0` to the table's rules

Comment: I'll try to get the HTML, but it's generated at runtime so is a bit difficult to get to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `border-collapse` property to the table to make the borders smaller:

```css
.dashboard{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.dashboard th {
  background-color: green;
  border: 0px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="dashboard">
  <tr>
    <th>Should be green border</th>
    <th>Should be green border</th>
    <th>Should be green border</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can than specify a border width of your own:

```css
.dashboard {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.dashboard th {
    background-color: green;
    border: 5px solid red; /* Just for demo */
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="dashboard">
  <tr>
    <th>Should be green border</th>
    <th>Should be green border</th>
    <th>Should be green border</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two points in your question:

1. if you set `border:0` it would not get the color.
2. in tables you should use `border-collapse: collapse;` to eliminate the gap as appears on your snapshot.
   I think the following fix would do the job:

```css
table.dashboard {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: #fff;
}

table.dashboard td {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

table.dashboard th {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}





/* just to tidy the page, not part of the answer ;) */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="dashboard">
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 1</td>
      <td>item 2</td>
      <td>item 3</td>
      <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 1</td>
      <td>item 2</td>
      <td>item 3</td>
      <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 1</td>
      <td>item 2</td>
      <td>item 3</td>
      <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 1</td>
      <td>item 2</td>
      <td>item 3</td>
      <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change border: **style="border:0px;"** solid green; to border: **1px** solid green; or you want to increase pixel as per your need.

```
     .dashboard th {
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid green;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}
```